# Python module initialization : good practices

Tags: python, module

When importing a custom module, I would like a given `initialize()` function to be run. The purpose of this function is mainly to initialize the global variables of the module.

Is calling the function inside `mymodule.py` frowned upon? Is it worth it to convert my module into a package and create a `__init__.py` file? Or should I just call the `initialize()` function from the main file that will import `mymodule`?

My question is somehow related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395797/python-module-initialization) but the answers do not satisfy me 100%

Comment: Can you give us more information? In what circumtances? Can you provide an example?

Comment: What is it about the linked answer that you feel doesn't answer your problem?

Comment: The purpose of the `initialize` function is to initialize the global variables of the module.

Answer (score 0):

A package is only necessary if you have more than one module, to package together. If your initialize is somehow work intensive you could the importing program decide when and how to initialize, otherwise all initialize inside your module.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to creating a module, you want those who will be using it to have the fewest steps to perform, and thus the least risk of error.
So, creating a `__init__.py` that is capable of doing all the initialization itself is a good solution.

It's part of the very philosophy behind the existence of modules: those who use a module don't want to have to tune internal details which are of no use to them.